# Floating div to right

Tags: html, css

In the following HTML, the .left has float:right, which cannot be changed. Is it still possible to move the .right div to the right side without changing the float:right in the .left div?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">   
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="left">This should be left.</div>
    </div>
     <div class="right">This should be right</div>    
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box{
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;    
}

.left{
    width: 100px;
    float: right;    /* cannot change */
    border: 1px solid blue;     
}

.right{
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/y5UEu/

Comment: Let me ask the stupid question: why can't you change the style on the left div?

Comment: What CAN you change? Can you change the HTML?

Comment: What's meant by "cannot change"? If you just leave that rule, but add `float: left;` *afterwards*, it'll [work just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/V6uFR/).

Comment: YES if you have fixed width example you have your `wrapper` width:600px; `left` width:300px `right` width:300px; my question is what is your reason why you want to float it `right` knowing you want it to be left

Comment: -1 Please edit your question to reflect the questions in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do this

html

```
<div class="box">   
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="left leftCol">This should be left.</div>
    </div>
     <div class="right">This should be right</div>    
</div>
```

css

```
.box{
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;    
}

.left{
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid blue;     
}

.right{
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.leftCol {
    float:left !important;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/y5UEu/4/)

Answer (score 2):

You can put your right div before left div.

```
<div class="box">   
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="right">This should be right</div>  
        <div class="left">This should be left.</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5UEu/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="right">This should be right</div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">This should be left.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

If you can't change the html structure,
you can apply some css to the wrap class,
since it's already there.

```
.wrap {
    width: 198px;
    float: left;
}
```

Width 198px is to cop with your border.
You can change this to whatever you want, to meet your requirement.

The float left property on .wrap class can give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

try with this

Add this to the Css Code :

```
    .wrap{
```

float: left;
}

HTML:

```
<div class="box">   
   <div class="right">This should be right</div>   
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">This should be left.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply define:

> .left { float: left !important; }

This will supplant the existing `.left {float:right;}`

*I assume that you cannot change the HTML, so this is a solution that works in situations where you apply a custom CSS to an existing website.*